# How to filter dataframe columns that start with something and end with something

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this piece of code currently that works as intended

```
val rules_list = df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("rule")).toList
```

However this is including some columns that I don't want. How would I add a second filter to this so that the total filter is "columns that start with 'rule' and end with any integer value"

So it should return "rule_1" in the list of columns but not "rule_1_modified"

Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: Why not use some kind of regex?

Comment: yeah it's a good idea. I'm just not very well versed with regex. do you have an implementation you could share? something that starts with a string match and ends with an integer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's Regex module like this

```
import re

columns = df.columns;
rules_list = [];
    for col_name in range(len(columns)):
      rules_list += re.findall('rule[_][0-9]',columns[col_name])
print(rules_list)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP is using Scala, but I'm sure this same regex could be used for that too.

Comment: okay, i didn't notice the scala tag, you can try the regex anyways .

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a regex expression to your filter:

```
val rules_list = data.columns.filter(c => c.startsWith("rule") && c.matches("^.*\\d$")).toList
```